# pyqt5のレイアウトでボタンとボタンの間の隙間をなくしたい

Tags: python, pyqt

pyqt5のレイアウトでボタンとボタンの間の隙間をなくしたいです。例えば次のようなコードを書いたとします。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5 import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",20)

        btn1=QPushButton("1")
        btn1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        btn2=QPushButton("2")
        btn2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        btn3=QPushButton("3")
        btn3.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        btn4=QPushButton("4")
        btn4.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)


        layout=QHBoxLayout()

        layout2=QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(btn2)
        layout2.addWidget(btn3)
        qw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        qw.setLayout(layout2)

        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(qw)
        layout.addWidget(btn4)
        layout.addLayout(layout2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Absolute')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなボタンのレイアウトが出力されます。
[image: 画像]
ここで、ボタンとボタンの間にある隙間をほとんど完全になくしたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout.setSpacing(0)`,`layout2.setSpacing(0)`とすることでwidget間の隙間を最小にできると思います。いかがでしょうか?

＃メソッドはそれぞれ`QHBoxLayout.setSpacing()`、`QVBoxLayout.setSpacing()`です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！お陰様で無事に動作してくれました。